# How Java Selenium WebDriver code works

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm pretty new in Java so, from what I've read, you need a public static void main function to run a Java applications. However, using Selenium WebDriver and TestNG I have Java code but with no main function. Who decides and where what methods to run, in what order and everything? I know that there are xml files where you can mention what methods to run, what classes, etc. but I'm interested in what happens "behind the scenes". There are cases when only the class is specified is the xml file so how does the compiler know in what order to run the methods and which class to use (there are classes derived from other classes, there are instances of webdriver but I have no idea where is the code for these instances, etc.)?

In C++ you knew you need the main function from which the applications starts. In PHP the code was read in the order it was written. But using Eclipse the methods seem to be called in alphabetical order.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question seems a little too broad. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Selenium, just TestNG and JUnit.
These are Test Frameworks used to run unit tests of your code. They do not run you application from `public static void main(String[] args)` method.
They look for methods annotated with `@Test` annotation and run all of them.

For example the following method will be run:

```
@Test
public void testSomeCode() {
    // test method here
}
```

Test frameworks may setup anything your program needs, such as databases, read CSV files, open the browsers and so on.

In general there is no ordering in test methods execution, they may be run in any order. TestNG provides some control over method dependencies, you can "group" methods or classes and have a structured execution order.

You could take a look at some [TestNG tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/testng-tutorials/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class{
```

public static void main(String[] args){
write you code here
}
}

little changes are there as compare to c++, try simple things first then go for TestNG.